# How to test a class which has properties being set using spring @values annotation?

Tags: spring, testing, constructor, annotations, mocking

I have a class which looks like the below

```
public class Abcd{

private  @Value("${username}")
String username;

private @Value("${password}")
String password;

public Abcd(){
   ServiceService serv = new ServiceService();
   Service port = serv.getServicePort();
   BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port;
   bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, username);
   bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);

}

public void getSomeValueMethod(){
....
}
```

**So how do I write a test for this? As I'm reading the values from the properties file, while testing when I try to call the constructor, as the username and password are null I get a null pointer exception and the test fails. Is there any way I can overcome this problem and test it successfully? How can I set those annotated values before calling the constructor?**

Comment: are you instanciating Abcd from spring or are you doing a new Abcd() ? you need to ask spring to give you an instance of this object, to have it inject automatically the dependencies.

Comment: Im doing new Abcd(). So as I have no values set before instantiating so the test fails.

Comment: I believe only the latest version of spring or at least above 3.1 would allow you to do that. to get Spring to create an instance of the object (and therefore inject in it all the dependencies required) reference a bean in your spring config file and ask it to give you an instance (exemple here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867997/instantiating-spring-beans-in-dynamically-created-classes)) or using junit with the spring test environment, create a field in your test class and annotate it with `@autowired`

Comment: the separate class that does all the  work in the constructor looks very strange. What is it trying to bind?.....upd: sorry I misread it—  it creates a separate instance of BindingProvider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like everything injected by Spring: by injecting them yourself in the unit test:

```
public class Abcd{

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public Abcd(@Value("${username}") userName, @Value("${password}") String password) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And in your unit test:

```
Abcd abcd = new Abcd("someUserName", "somePassword");
```

Remember that dependency injection's main goal is to be able to manually inject fake or mock dependencies in unit tests.