# How to set a value injected by Spring in a unit test?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

I am writing a Unit Test for the following class that is managed by Spring:

```
@Component
public class MyClass {
    @Value("${urlValue}")
    private String urlPath;
    private MyUrl url = new MyUrl(urlPath);

    public class MyUrl {
        MyUrl(String url) {
            if (url == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to set `urlValue` in the simplest way for my test. I tried the following:

```
public class MyClassTest {
    private MyClass mc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mc = new MyClass();
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(mc, "urlPath", "urlValue");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

    }
}
```

However the setting by reflection fails because it comes too late (`new MyUrl()` is called before and throws an Exception). What would be the easiest way to set `urlPath`, ideally (I assume) without changing the code, nor using a Spring context for the test ?

Comment: you can have it in `@Before` method

Comment: I don't really understand your answer (nor how it relates to the answer you linked to). I am very sorry for not understanding. The code snippet I added in my question is actually already in a @Before method, but I don't see how this changes anything. Can you please help me some more ?

Comment: can you add more code ? and i would also say don't create object like this `MyClass mc = new MyClass();` inside method. please add more code

Comment: I have added what I think is a full example of my situation. As you can see, I am already in a @Before, and I still get a NullPointerException.

Comment: The simplest way is to use [constructor injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.x/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-constructor-injection) instead of field injection. Then you can just instantiate it for your tests.

Comment: @LucasP and if I don't want to use constructor injection, is there another way ?

Comment: Deadpool, so do you agree that @Before won't solve my problem ? And in that case, do you have another solution ? Thank you very much.

Comment: probably this approach solves your problem 
@RonW https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594001/how-to-test-a-class-which-has-properties-being-set-using-spring-values-annotati

Answer (score 1):

For unit testing a Spring component you need to make its members setable from outside. The easiest way to do this is by using constructor injection. Field injection requires you to run a `@SpringBootTest`, which makes your unit test unreasonable slow as it creates a Spring context.

Have a look here: [guide to unit test in spring boot](https://reflectoring.io/unit-testing-spring-boot/)

You could do it like this (didn't check for correctness):

```
@Component
public class MyClass {
    private String urlPath;
    private MyUrl url;

    public MyClass(@Value("${urlValue}") String urlPath) {
        this.urlPath = urlPath;
        this.url = new MyUrl(urlPath)
    }

    public class MyUrl {
        MyUrl(String url) {
            if (url == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/exabrial/mockito-object-injection

We've created a JUnit Extension to solve this exact problem.

It's easy to use... see the README.md:

```
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ExtendWith({ MockitoExtension.class, InjectMapExtension.class })
public class MyControllerTest {
```